# How exactly did Voyager beat the Borg ship in the beginning of "Dark Frontier"?

Tags: star-trek

Was it that Voyager had Borg technology? Was it that something went wrong in the Borg's magnetic field?

All I saw was Starfleet photon torpedos destroy the Borg. How was that so?

Answer (score 7):

After the initial verbal exchange (*blah blah You will be assimilated blah, blah, Break off pursuit or Voyager will open fire blah, blah*) there was an exchange of weapon fire. During this exchange, the Borg ship's (not a cube or sphere but a probe) deflector shields are disabled.

It's important to note here that Seven of Nine is on the bridge at the auxiliary tactical console, not down in [Astrometrics](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Astrometrics). Apparently, Janeway has requested the temporary change of assignment for her tactical expertise against the Borg.

While the Collective instructs the probe's drones to regenerate and remodulate the shields, a Starfleet photon torpedo is beamed aboard the probe ship.

> A drone moves to disable it but as the drone is about to begin dismantling the torpedo it detonates, destroying the probe and all drones aboard.
>
> On Voyager's bridge, Janeway and Chakotay watch the explosion on the viewscreen. Both seem disappointed, Chakotay asks what happened as the goal was to merely disable the probe. Seven of Nine explains that the torpedo detonated near the power matrix, causing a chain reaction in the probe's systems. Janeway asks about survivors and Lt. Commander Tuvok reports that there were none.
> <sub>[source: Memory-Alpha - Dark Frontier](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Frontier_(episode))</sub>

So Seven of Nine's tactical plan to disable the Borg drone ship went pear-shaped due to a badly placed transport. The Voyager crew was left to salvage what little they find that remained.